display a datagrid inside a datagrid
I am working with MUI’s DataGrid to display a list of tasks. My goal is to have an expandable detail row directly under each task row when clicked. For now, I am trying to add a new row under the selected task with all columns spanned to display a simple message. However, I’m facing two issues:
The new detail row is not displaying as expected.
Although I can see the red background on the expanded row, the columns are not spanning, and no message is being displayed.
Here’s my current code:
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

export default function TaskTable({ tasks }) {
    const [expandedTaskId, setExpandedTaskId] = React.useState(null);

    // Colonnes pour les tâches
    const columns = [
        { field: "title", headerName: "Titre", width: 200 },
        { field: "description", headerName: "Description", width: 300 },
        { field: "status", headerName: "Statut", width: 120 },
        { field: "priority", headerName: "Priorité", width: 120 },
        { field: "startDate", headerName: "Date de début", width: 150 },
        { field: "dueDate", headerName: "Date de fin", width: 150 },
        { field: "createdAt", headerName: "Créé le", width: 150 },
        { field: "updatedAt", headerName: "Mis à jour le", width: 150 },
        {
            field: "files",
            headerName: "Fichiers",
            width: 200,
            renderCell: (params) => (
                <ul>
                    {(params.value || []).map((file, index) => (
                        <li key={index}>
                            <a href={file.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                                {file.name}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            ),
        },
    ];

    // Fonction pour afficher/masquer le panneau des sous-tâches
    const handleRowClick = (params) => {
        setExpandedTaskId((prevId) => (prevId === params.row.id ? null : params.row.id));
    };

    //  les lignes de la table principale incluant les lignes cachées pour les sous-tâches
    const rows = tasks.flatMap((task) => {
        const mainRow = {
            id: task._id,
            title: task.title,
            description: task.description,
            status: task.status,
            priority: task.priority,
            startDate: task.startDate ? new Date(task.startDate).toLocaleDateString() : "N/A",
            dueDate: task.dueDate ? new Date(task.dueDate).toLocaleDateString() : "N/A",
            createdAt: task.createdAt ? new Date(task.createdAt).toLocaleDateString() : "N/A",
            updatedAt: task.updatedAt ? new Date(task.updatedAt).toLocaleDateString() : "N/A",
            files: task.files || [],
        };

        // Si la tâche est développée, ajouter une ligne supplémentaire avec un texte
        if (task._id === expandedTaskId) {
            return [
                mainRow,
                {
                    id: `${task._id}-expanded`,
                    message: "Détails supplémentaires pour cette tâche",
                    isExpandedRow: true,
                    colSpan: columns.length,
                },
            ];
        }

        return [mainRow];
    });

    return (
        <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <DataGrid
                rows={rows}
                columns={columns}
                pageSize={5}
                getRowId={(row) => row.id}
                onRowClick={(params) => {
                    if (!params.row.isExpandedRow) handleRowClick(params);
                }}
                getRowClassName={(params) =>
                    params.row.isExpandedRow ? "expanded-row" : ""
                }
                components={{
                    Row: (props) => (
                        <>
                            <props.components.Row {...props} />
                            {props.row.isExpandedRow && (
                                <Box
                                    sx={{
                                        pl: 2,
                                        width: "100%",
                                        bgcolor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)",
                                        gridColumn: `span ${columns.length}`,

                                    }}
                                >
                                    <Box sx={{ padding: 1, color: "black" }}>
                                        <p>Test</p>
                                        {/* <p>{props.row.message}</p> */}
                                    </Box>
                                </Box>
                            )}
                        </>
                    ),
                }}
                sx={{
                    "& .MuiDataGrid-row.expanded-row": {
                        bgcolor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)",
                        color: "black",
                        "& .MuiDataGrid-cell": {
                            display: "flex",
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            fontStyle: "italic",
                        },
                    },
                }}
            />
        </Box>
    );
}

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have an update, I can see the nested datagrid now in the second cell but I can't use colspan for dynamic col and also the height dont change so for now I need just to adjust the height and the width of the cell if the row is added
"use client";
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import SubTaskTable from "./SubTaskTable";

export default function TaskTable({ tasks }) {
  const [expandedTaskId, setExpandedTaskId] = React.useState(null);

  const columns = [
    { field: "title", headerName: "Titre", width: 200 },
    {
      field: "description",
      headerName: "Description",
      width: 300,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        if (params.row.isSubTask) {
          return (
            <Box
              sx={{
                gridColumn: `span ${columns.length}`, 
                bgcolor: "rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.5)",
                padding: 2,
                textAlign: "center",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                minHeight: 250, 
                display: "flex",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            >
              <SubTaskTable subTasks={params.row.subTasks || []} />
            </Box>
          );
        }
        return params.value;
      },
    },
    { field: "status", headerName: "Statut", width: 120 },
    { field: "priority", headerName: "Priorité", width: 120 },
    { field: "startDate", headerName: "Date de début", width: 150 },
    { field: "dueDate", headerName: "Date de fin", width: 150 },
    { field: "createdAt", headerName: "Créé le", width: 150 },
    { field: "updatedAt", headerName: "Mis à jour le", width: 150 },
    {
      field: "files",
      headerName: "Fichiers",
      width: 200,
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <ul>
          {(params.value || []).map((file, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <a href={file.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                {file.name}
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ),
    },
  ];

  const handleRowClick = (params) => {
    setExpandedTaskId((prevId) => (prevId === params.row.id ? null : params.row.id));
  };

  const rows = tasks.flatMap((task) => {
    const mainRow = {
      id: task._id,
      title: task.title,
      description: task.description,
      status: task.status,
      priority: task.priority,
      startDate: task.startDate ? new Date(task.startDate).toLocaleDateString() : "N/A",
      dueDate: task.dueDate ? new Date(task.dueDate).toLocaleDateString() : "N/A",
      createdAt: task.createdAt ? new Date(task.createdAt).toLocaleDateString() : "N/A",
      updatedAt: task.updatedAt ? new Date(task.updatedAt).toLocaleDateString() : "N/A",
      files: task.files || [],
    };

    if (task._id === expandedTaskId) {
      return [
        mainRow,
        {
          id: `${task._id}-subTask`,
          isSubTask: true,
          title: "",
          description: "",
          subTasks: task.subTasks || [],
        },
      ];
    }

    return [mainRow];
  });

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        getRowId={(row) => row.id}
        onRowClick={(params) => {
          if (!params.row.isSubTask) handleRowClick(params);
        }}
        sx={{
          "& .MuiDataGrid-row.isSubTask .MuiDataGrid-cell": {
            display: "none",
          },
          "& .MuiDataGrid-row.isSubTask .MuiDataGrid-cell--withRenderer": {
            display: "block",
            gridColumn: `span ${columns.length}`,
          },
          "& .MuiDataGrid-row.isSubTask": {
            bgcolor: "rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.5)",
          },
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}

